# Set a zero point and if the value is lower or higher than this it is shown as -value or +value

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have an input of 0 to 359 (ie a compass).

I want to set a zero point and if the value is lower or higher than this it is shown as -value or +value.

Example:

```
Zero Point: 2
Input: 340 => Output: -22
Input: 22 => Output: 20
```

or

```
Zero Point: 40
Input: 30 => Output: -10
Input: 50 => Output: 10
```

So no matter where the compass 'is', the output is always relative to the zero point.

PS: Or even shorter: How do I convert a repeating sequence of 0->359 into a linear sequence that I can work with like with a normal number line? So if 359 is reached 2 times counting upwards the function tells me it is at 720(I might've missed the right value here for 1° or 2°) and not 359?

Comment: What have you tried? Also there isn't enough information here to help at all..Set what? what are your outputting to? how are you determining the output from those inputs?

Comment: Why the output for 340 is -22? Where is the border between plus and minus values? Did you try to create such method on your own? Paste your code.

Comment: @filipko The border is the zero point.

Comment: @user2348735 I think you don't understand. Let's say we have input 182. How should we know if its output is 180 or -179?

Comment: @user2348735: So is it not possible to show a simple arithmetic operation(e.g. subtraction) to demonstrate the logic? Then there is no solution at all, otherwise you have already the solution.

Comment: I'll give you a start because I've figured out the basic logic but there isn't any logic in what makes your output negative or positive.

`y = (360 + zeroPoint) - x`

Comment: @filipko Good point. Let's phrase it this way: Let's picture a row of numbers that look like this 0->359->0->359->0... Whereas the first "0" is another "0" than the second "0" and so on. We could internally have a counter that increases each time a 359 becomes a zero and decrease if a 0 becomes a 359. So temporarily we could count from 0 -> 359 -> (0+1+359) -> (0+359+359) -> ...

Comment: Or even shorter: How do I convert a repeating sequence of 0->359 into a linear sequence that I can work with like with a normal number line? So if 359 is reached 2 times counting upwards the function tells me it is at 720(I might've missed the right value here for 1° or 2°) and not 359?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want an output from -179 to 180 and the zeropoint can be from 0 to 359

```
int output(int deg, int zeropoint)
    {
        var relative = deg - zeropoint;
        if (relative > 180)
            relative -= 360;
        else if (relative < -179)
            relative += 360;
        return relative;
    }
```

Comment: you should change your answer to use `else` instead of `else if` but otherwise +1

Comment: no - if the relative falls already in the expected range, there should be no normalization (neither add nor subtract 360)

Comment: ah sorry I missed that bit - not awake yet!

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you ask, but I'm not confident about your requirements. Basically, given a 'clock' of a certain size, a point to get the relative distance from and an input value, it will find the smallest distance to the point on the 'clock', either negative or positive.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(getRelativeValue(2, 360, 340)); //-22
        Console.WriteLine(getRelativeValue(2, 360, 22));  // 20
        Console.WriteLine(getRelativeValue(2, 360, 178)); // 176
        Console.Read();
    }

    static int getRelativeValue(int point, int upperBound, int value)
    {
        value %= upperBound;
        int lowerBoundPoint = -(upperBound - value + point);
        int upperBoundPoint = (value - point);

        if (Math.Abs(lowerBoundPoint) > Math.Abs(upperBoundPoint))
        {
            return upperBoundPoint;
        }
        else
        {
            return lowerBoundPoint;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = input - zero > 180 ? input - zero - 360 : input - zero;
```